# How to import data from MS Access to Sql Server by coding

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, ms-access

I need to import an Access database by code to Sql Server. My software that is made in C # for many years has been integrated into an Access database. From now  we are migrating to Sql Server and the intention is in the upgrade to the next version the system will only work with Sql Server. I think at first of creating a Sql database with the same names of tables and columns and the software read the Access tables and save the data in the Sql database. Is there any other more practical way to do this by coding?

I've been searching and found just tools ready, but nothing by coding.

Comment: Why do this in code if its a one off task? SSMA/SQL Server Migration Assistant can do this and give you a good starting point.

Comment: Why in this case I would have to access computer by computer of each user and install the SqlServer to make the migration. The intention is that by the software, in the form created by visual studio, when updating the software for the new version, the user himself can migrate to the new database just by clicking an Ok button, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets say your access Database table has 3 columns, 1st one is type of integer, 2nd is string (varchar) nad 3rd one is DateTime (date).

So this is the code you have to do for passing data from Access to Sql Server:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
// get data from access
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connString1"))
{
     using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM MyTable", conn))
           da.Fill(table);
}

//insert data into Sql server:
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString2"))
{
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
             cmd.Connection = conn;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.Int);  
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", SqlDbType.CarChar, 50);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", SqlDbType.DateTime);
             conn.Open();

             for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                    cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][0]);
                    cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = table.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i][2]);
                    try
                    {
                          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                           break;
                    }
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking of doing. So does it mean that there is no simpler way to do that?

Comment: its the simplest way to do it through code.

Comment: @vijayvikcs Tkx!